# What is the most generic spin mixed state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, spinors, density-operator

For a spin generic mixed state $\rho$. How should I write $\rho$?

$\rho_1 = q_1 |\uparrow\rangle \langle \uparrow| + q_2 |\downarrow\rangle \langle \downarrow|$

or

$\rho_2 = q_1 |\uparrow\rangle \langle \uparrow| + q_2 |\uparrow\rangle \langle \downarrow| + q_3 |\downarrow \rangle \langle \uparrow| + q_4 |\downarrow\rangle \langle \downarrow|$

I actually wonder whether $|\downarrow \rangle \langle \uparrow|$ makes sence. I came out with this because my first guess would be:

$\rho = q_1|\chi_x^+ \rangle\langle\chi_x^+|+q_2|\chi_x^- \rangle\langle\chi_x^-|+q_3|\chi_y^+ \rangle\langle\chi_y^+|+q_4|\chi_y^- \rangle\langle\chi_y^-|+q_5|\chi_z^+ \rangle\langle\chi_z^+|+q_6|\chi_z^- \rangle\langle\chi_z^-|$

which reduces to $\rho_2$ form, since I am presuming:

$|\chi_x^{\pm}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|\uparrow \rangle\pm|\downarrow \rangle)$

$|\chi_y^{\pm}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|\uparrow \rangle\pm i|\downarrow \rangle)$

$|\chi_z^{+}\rangle = |\uparrow \rangle$

$|\chi_z^{-}\rangle = |\downarrow \rangle$

But then, $q_2$ and $q_3$ would be complex, which I think they can't, right?

I feel that I am misunderstanding something very fundamental.

Comment: What would be the point of writing the density matrix as a matrix if we only allowed it to have diagonal entries?

Comment: I am claculating the time derivative of the polarization vector. Which is $\frac{d}{dt} \langle \vec{\sigma} \rangle = \frac{1}{i \hbar} Tr( \rho \vec{\sigma})$ as I understand.